# How to create a Picture in HTML with the correct height

Tags: html

I have a header which I want responsive so that it only loads the relevant sized image.  I've been using a Picture tag but it causes a CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift) because it will only size the height for 20px rather than 48px.  I've not set any style to affect the picture so can't work out why the Picture reserves only 20px and then when the image loads, it sizes to 48px.  When I specify the width, the width works correctly.  Any tips?

```
<html>
    <header>
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width:624px)" type="image/webp" srcset="/pictures/site.webp"/>
            <source media="(min-width:624px)" type="image/png" srcset="/pictures/site.png"/>
            <source media="(max-width:623px)" type="image/webp" srcset="/pictures/site.webp"/>
            <img src="/pictures/ugweb.png" width="340" height="48" alt="Site" title="Site"/>
        </picture>
    </header>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ammm if I got your problem correctly I assume you will have to pre define the minimum height of the image header img {min-height:48px} or maybe by try loading an bade 64 of an empty image height of 48 px another thing you might want to check is what if you change the display of the image to block?  if you can post fidlle of your code I might be able to help more than assumptions

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by an bade 64?

Comment: I meant base64 image something like that: 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAwCAYAAADQMxCBAAAAEElEQVR42mNk+M9QzzhyCAChB0fR7uEn3gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">

so basically this image is height of 48px and there would not be loading time because it is inline, so once other image loaded you can change the base 64 image src to the original one.

Comment: you also may want to check loading eager attr: loading="eager"

Comment: I updated the html above, when you view the page in Chrome using Developer Tools, the image is 48px height but the picture is only 20px so when the image loads, there is CLS.  I'm not inlining the image as base64, I'm going to try the loading to force them to load it first.

Comment: so if this is the case it definitely something with css of the page, You might want to use !important to the css / inline style of the image height just to verify this is the case.

Comment: I want edit question.